# Extracting words from a complex multi-paragraph document and output them as a multiline comma separated file

Tags: python

I have a document with following formatting;

```
    QUERY: STBZIP38
     Length of Query Sequence:       2000 bp     | Nucleotide Frequencies:  A -  0.34   G -  0.16   T -  0.35   C -  0.15
    
    
     TFBS AC: RSP00073//OS: tobacco (Nicotiana tabacum) /GENE: synthetic oligonucleotides/TFBS: PA /BF: TAF-1
     Motifs on "+" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00391     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         421  tCCACGTGGC      430 (Mism.= 1)
    
     Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00391     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         430  GCCACGTGGa      421 (Mism.= 1)
    
     TFBS AC: RSP00153//OS: Parsley, Petroselinum crispum /GENE: CHS/TFBS: Box II /BF: CPRF-1; CPRF-2; CPRF-3;
     Motifs on "+" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00358     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         422  CCACGTGGCa      431 (Mism.= 1)
    
     TFBS AC: RSP00154//OS: parsley (Petroselinum crispum) /GENE: CHS/TFBS: ACE (CHS) /BF: bZIP factors CPRF1, CPRF4
     Motifs on "+" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00358     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         422  CCACGTGGCa      431 (Mism.= 1)
Totally      50 motifs of    43 different TFBSs have been found
____________________________________________________________

 QUERY: STBZIP17
 Length of Query Sequence:       2000 bp     | Nucleotide Frequencies:  A -  0.37   G -  0.13   T -  0.39   C -  0.11


 TFBS AC: RSP00577//OS: tomato (Lycopersicon esculentum), Lycopersicon esculentum /GENE: rbcS3A/TFBS: AT-rich FF2 /BF: unknown nuclear factor
 Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00187     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
     206  AATAATTAaAcATTAATTAA      187 (Mism.= 2)

 TFBS AC: RSP00797//OS: potato (Solanum tuberosum) /GENE: patatin 21/TFBS: SURE-1 /BF: SURF
 Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00440     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
    1027  TAAAGAATAaAAAAAaaAA     1009 (Mism.= 3)

 TFBS AC: RSP00864//OS: arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: STK/TFBS: GA-5 /BF: BPC1
 Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00260     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
    1966  AGAGAGAGA     1958 (Mism.= 0)
```

The output I want is as follows;

```
STBZIP38    RSP00073//OS
STBZIP38    RSP00153//OS
STBZIP38    RSP00154//OS
STBZIP17    RSP00577//OS
STBZIP17    RSP00797//OS
STBZIP17    RSP00864//OS
```

I was looking at a couple of tutorials and trying to use the split function (I am still learning A,B,C of python). I started with the following, things I am still trying to figure out is how to grab only the word after the term I use (ex. QUERY: then only grab STBZIP38 then the number after TFBC AC:),.
I really appreciate it if someone can help me in regard. Thanks in advance.

```
with open ('Softberry.txt') as fo:
for rec in fo:
    print((rec.split('QUERY:')) + ',' +(rec.split('TFBS AC:')))
```

Comment: I urge you to learn the python `re` module. [Al Sweigart's PyCon 2017 talk on regular expressions in python is a very good start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abrcJ9MpF60).

Comment: Sure, I will. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks. Here is how it ended up with. Big thanks for the help given by CYREX and xelf (Reddit).

```
with open('Softberry.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(' QUERY:'):
            query = line.split(':', 1)[1].strip()
        if 'AC:' in line:
            ac = line.split('AC:')[1].split(':')[0].strip()
            print(query,ac)
```

Answer (score 1):

A great boilerplate to start with, I prepared exact regex patterns, do the rest. PS: what you need is **readlines() method + regex**, no splitting!

```
import re

s = """QUERY: STBZIP38
     Length of Query Sequence:       2000 bp     | Nucleotide Frequencies:  A -  0.34   G -  0.16   T -  0.35   C -  0.15
    
    
     TFBS AC: RSP00073//OS: tobacco (Nicotiana tabacum) /GENE: synthetic oligonucleotides/TFBS: PA /BF: TAF-1
     Motifs on "+" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00391     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         421  tCCACGTGGC      430 (Mism.= 1)
    
     Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00391     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         430  GCCACGTGGa      421 (Mism.= 1)
    
     TFBS AC: RSP00153//OS: Parsley, Petroselinum crispum /GENE: CHS/TFBS: Box II /BF: CPRF-1; CPRF-2; CPRF-3;
     Motifs on "+" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00358     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         422  CCACGTGGCa      431 (Mism.= 1)
    
     TFBS AC: RSP00154//OS: parsley (Petroselinum crispum) /GENE: CHS/TFBS: ACE (CHS) /BF: bZIP factors CPRF1, CPRF4
     Motifs on "+" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00358     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
         422  CCACGTGGCa      431 (Mism.= 1)
Totally      50 motifs of    43 different TFBSs have been found
 QUERY: STBZIP17
 Length of Query Sequence:       2000 bp     | Nucleotide Frequencies:  A -  0.37   G -  0.13   T -  0.39   C -  0.11


 TFBS AC: RSP00577//OS: tomato (Lycopersicon esculentum), Lycopersicon esculentum /GENE: rbcS3A/TFBS: AT-rich FF2 /BF: unknown nuclear factor
 Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00187     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
     206  AATAATTAaAcATTAATTAA      187 (Mism.= 2)

 TFBS AC: RSP00797//OS: potato (Solanum tuberosum) /GENE: patatin 21/TFBS: SURE-1 /BF: SURF
 Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00440     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
    1027  TAAAGAATAaAAAAAaaAA     1009 (Mism.= 3)

 TFBS AC: RSP00864//OS: arabidopsis (Arabidopsis thaliana) /GENE: STK/TFBS: GA-5 /BF: BPC1
 Motifs on "-" Strand: Mean Exp. Number   0.00260     Up.Conf.Int.  1     Found   1
    1966  AGAGAGAGA     1958 (Mism.= 0)"""
         
pat1='STB.*\d*'

pat2 = 'RSP.*OS'

m = re.findall(pat1,s)

n = re.findall(pat2, s)

#print(m, n)

print(m[0],  n[0])
print(m[0],  n[1])
print(m[0],  n[2])
print(m[1], n[3]) 
print(m[1],  n[4])
print(m[1],  n[5])
```

output

```
STBZIP38 RSP00073//OS
STBZIP38 RSP00153//OS
STBZIP38 RSP00154//OS
STBZIP17 RSP00577//OS
STBZIP17 RSP00797//OS
STBZIP17 RSP00864//OS
```

Comment: Thanks :) . Used to hate coding (programing in general) but now regret that mistake! 
quick question; following part - I have nearly 100 pages (only copied half of the input). What is the best way to compact this part?
~~~ #print(m, n)

print(m[0],  n[0])
print(m[0],  n[1])
print(m[0],  n[2])
print(m[1], n[3]) 
print(m[1],  n[4])
print(m[1],  n[5]) ~~~

Comment: pls find the doc here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16R__MlqfvKhF5cq5thi8FNZaouJi9K5u/view?usp=sharing
Thank you!

Comment: I tried many ways but its much more harder to manipulate than i thought.. The Good news is i found a very easy way to do the job  using regex on notepad++. But iam tired now and gonna do it 2morrow. see ya.

Comment: basically you will have to do it manually but its the easiest solution i found, download notepadd++ and use the regex pattern used to find your matched expressions then manually align them. Else, an advanced coder could offer you programming approach. Regards.